# Sqoop CLI Kerberos Error with Kerberized CDH

Tags: hadoop, kerberos, sqoop

I've recently Kerberized a Cloudera Hadoop cluster.  All services and shells are fine (impala, hive, hue, etc.) except for Sqoop.  The below job used to run fine:

```
$ sqoop job -fs hdfs://<namenode>:8020 --create myJob \
-- import --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver \
--connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager \
--connect jdbc:mysql://<mysqldb>:3306/<dbname> --username <username> \
-P --table <tablename> --target-dir /raw/ \
--incremental append --check-column <table-pk>
```

Job is created without error.  On job run, it fails, complaining that SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.

```
$  sqoop job --exec myJob

16/03/01 11:56:26 WARN security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hadoop_admin (auth:SIMPLE) cause:org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]
16/03/01 11:56:26 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:73)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:2097)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$19.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1214)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$19.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1210)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1210)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1409)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:145)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:269)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:142)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1307)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1304)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1304)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1325)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.doSubmitJob(ImportJobBase.java:196)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runJob(ImportJobBase.java:169)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:266)
at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:673)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:497)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.JobTool.execJob(JobTool.java:228)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.JobTool.run(JobTool.java:283)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1472)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1403)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:230)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:752)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:252)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:104)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:2095)
... 29 more
```

I am using Kerberos/KDC and have configured it based on Cloudera specs: http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cm_sg_sec_troubleshooting.html - my config files are the same, except of course with my realm replaced, and as I said, all other services are functioning and starting up fine with Kerberos enabled.

I've updated the /etc/sqoop2/conf/sqoop.properties with the following lines:

```
org.apache.sqoop.security.authentication.type=KERBEROS
org.apache.sqoop.security.authentication.handler=org.apache.sqoop.security.authentication.KerberosAuthenticationHandler
org.apache.sqoop.security.authentication.kerberos.principal=sqoop2/<fqdn>@<REALM>
org.apache.sqoop.security.authentication.kerberos.keytab=/etc/sqoop2/conf/sqoop2.keytab
org.apache.sqoop.security.authentication.kerberos.http.principal=HTTP/<fqdn>@<REALM>
org.apache.sqoop.security.authentication.kerberos.http.keytab=/etc/sqoop2/conf/sqoop2.keytab
org.apache.sqoop.security.authentication.enable.doAs=true
org.apache.sqoop.security.authentication.proxyuser.mapr.users=*
```

To generate the sqoop2.keytab I ran:

```
kadmin> xst -k /home/kerberos/sqoop2.keytab HTTP/<FQDN>@<REALM>
kadmin> xst -k /home/kerberos/sqoop2.keytab sqoop2/<fqdn>@<REALM>
```

I then moved the keytab file to /etc/sqoop2/conf and chmod'ed it to 400 and chowned it to sqoop2.

klist shows:

```
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000
Default principal: hadoop_admin@<REALM>

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
03/01/2016 11:28:14  03/01/2016 21:28:14  krbtgt/<REALM>@<REALM>
renew until 03/08/2016 11:28:14
```

Is there a step I'm missing?

Comment: Are you really sure that your `sqoop` command-line uses **Sqoop2**, and not the good old **Sqoop1**?

Comment: In the same shell that you try to run Sqoop, can you run `hdfs groups` to check that your default Hadoop conf files (in `/etc/hadoop/conf`) are up-to-date?

Comment: Regarding Sqoop2/1.  When running the shell it brings up: INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.5.1.  Checking into that, the installation has two sqoop folders: /etc/sqoop/ and /etc/sqoop2, but /etc/sqoop/conf does not contain a sqoop.properties file, but the sqoop-site.xml.  Am I supposed to add Kerberos details to /etc/sqoop/conf/sqoop-site.xml?

Comment: Regarding hdfs groups: I'm running sqoop on a non-hdfs node, but if I run hdfs groups on the name node, then I get hadoop_admin@<REALM> : hadoop_admin adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare hadoop hdfs

Comment: The "UserGroupInformation" class gets the security settings from `core-site.xml` property `hadoop.security.authentication` and so on.